# Change of Variables by u substitution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, substitution, multiple-integral

Normally when we do a change of variables with multiple integrals (scalar valued function) we take the standard approach:
$$\int F(x,y) \cdot dx \cdot dy =\int F(g(u,v)) \cdot Jac(g) \cdot du\cdot dv$$

If I instead do u substitution with 
$$dx = \partial_u x\cdot du + \partial_v x\cdot dv$$ and
$$dy = \partial_u y\cdot du + \partial_v y\cdot dv$$

Then dx*dy comes out nasty. Is there any way I can simplify it to get the standard approach?

Answer (score 2):

You need to think of $dx \, dy$ as really being the "wedge product" $dx \wedge dy$ (read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra)). Then if you do your substitution, the Jacobian formula should pop out. I'm going to use the subscript notation for derivatives to make things easier to read: $x_u = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$, etc...

So first just substitute as you suggest for $dx$ and $dy$, and then distribute:

$$
\begin {align*}
dx \wedge dy &= \left( x_u \, du + x_v \, dv \right) \wedge \left( y_u \, du + y_v \, dv \right) \\
&= x_uy_u \, du \wedge du \, + \, x_vy_v dv \wedge dv \, + \, x_uy_v du \wedge dv \, + \, x_v y_u dv \wedge du
\end {align*}
$$

Since the wedge product is skew-symmetric, $du \wedge du =0$ and $dv \wedge dv = 0$, and also $dv \wedge du = - du \wedge dv$. So this all simplifies down to

$$ dx \wedge dy = \left( x_uy_v - x_vy_u \right) du \wedge dv $$

The coefficient $x_uy_v-x_vy_u$ is exactly the Jacobian determinant in the formula which you call the "standard approach".